# How to consume response of one rest api in another rest API java Microservices?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, microservices

I have 2 micro services running :-

```
1] user 
   running on tomcat port :8081,
   database name:  user.
2] order
   running on tomcat port :8082,
   database name:  order.
```

I have a REST API in order micro service as shown below:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/order/getdetail", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
    public List registerCustomer() {
    List list=new ArrayList();
    list.add("aaa");
    list.add("aab");
    return list;
}
```

now How can I consume this micro in user

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/user/getdetail", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")

   // need to call REST API /order/getdetail and return list
    }
```

As I am new to micro services I am not aware of to communicate between micros?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done. Spring provides `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` which is an HTTP client. You may refer this [article](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) for more details. Also it allows you just to deal with java objects, instead of JSON data. It is easier to deal with Java objects. Spring takes care on serializing and deserializing between objects and JSON data.

For an example, let's say you need to submit a simple `GET` request to the downstream rest endpoint and obtain the response as a DTO class. The following code would do that.

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseDTO responseDTO = restTemplate.getForEntity("/api/endpoint", ResponseDTO.class).getBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTTP Client that would pass the message.  In JAX-RS you'd have the JAX-RS Clients.

If you use [MS4J from WSO2](https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/tree/master/client/src/main/java/org/wso2/msf4j/client) they provide 
* Feign which goes on top of Apache HTTP Client

For my own framework [app-ms](https://github.com/trajano/app-ms) I use RestEasy's JAX-RS implementation but utilize vert.x as my HTTP client so I can get better performance.